# Listening for adb connect / disconnect

Tags: android, adb

I have an Android app that I'd like to display an indicator whether the device is connected to a host over adb, and so some things programmatically based on that. I'm not able to find any documentation on how to listen for an event indicating the android device is connected over USB / ADB. Does a broadcasted event exist?

The host machine will not be mounting it as USB Mass Storage, MTP, or CTP, but just connecting over adb.